# Make gVim use last compiled version of vim

Tags: vim

I've compiled the latest version of vim with some options.

Is there a way to make gVim use the same vim as in the console ?

Comment: You need to compile vim source with the right options to get the gui binaries. Read `src/INSTALL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, `gvim` == `vim -g`; it's the same binary. So, if you have compiled Vim with GUI support, `make install` should install consistent versions of both `vim` and `gvim`.